# Recursive copy of directory from web to device file system in Cordova

Tags: javascript, cordova, xmlhttprequest, cordova-plugins

I want copy all files in a web directory on a webserver, and ideally in its component subdirectories, into local device storage for Android and iOS in Cordova using javascript and/or cordova plugins.

The use case is to copy an entire (smallish) webapp/page from a remote webserver (that we control, and where we posted the content) into local storage on the device.  This will be used for a form of hot code push for a cordova app.

It's possible to copy files using cordova-plugin-file-transfer:

https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-file/

or in a more standards-compliant way using XMLHttpRequest (XHR):

https://cordova.apache.org/blog/2017/10/18/from-filetransfer-to-xhr2.html

How does one copy an entire directory tree, overwriting an existing one, in device storage.

Preferable: method to include error handling for the case that something prevents the full copy from happening, possibly resulting in a partial copy or a corrupted directory.

Is there an api or combination of apis that do this already?  If not, does someone have or know of code to accomplish this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can look at hydration of phonegap for hot push :

http://docs.phonegap.com/phonegap-build/tools/hydration/

I think it may be suitable for your need.

However, be very careful with hot code push because apple doesn't like it very much and it's rather contrary to their guideline.

Comment: Thanks, but this is a cordova project not a phonegap project.  Do you know of a good library that does hot code push for cordova?  I haven't been able to find one.  I found a couple of old/deprecated ones but nothing current.

Comment: I had the same problem as you, a lot of dead libraries/plugins and I had to migrate to phonegap. So I won't be of much help to you, sorry....

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I'm actually just in the process of doing that now.  Haven't used PhoneGap before.  Did you find any important gotchas (like things that are impossible in PhoneGap that some Cordova apps require), or does it go relatively smoothly?  Thanks again.

Comment: Note, I use PhonegapBuild which is Phonegap's on-the-cloud build service. 
The biggest problem I had was to automate the build process but without PhonegapBuild you shouldn't have this problem. Anyway, their API is now very powerful.
For Phonegap in itself, the only fear I have is that one day developers will not go fast enough to be compatible with the new Android or Apple products. But for now it has never been the case.
Otherwise no worries after 2 years of work.
Currently they both have a very similar API

Comment: If you wouldn't mind answering one more question that would be very helpful to me and I hope to others... I got Phonegap setup, & successfully used 'Hydration' to hot code push.  I have not been able to find any information about how to configure the base hydration displays/behavior (which is not production-compatible in my opinion) anywhere online, or in the Adobe docs.  Base behavior is that on first download, and on restart,  app users see an ugly, unstyled black and white screen saying eg "Initializing, Please wait".  Are there configuration options? Many new users will bounce, not wait.

Comment: These cannot be customized. Hydration is intended as a development tool, and should not be included in production builds.
In any case, Apple's guideline rule 2.5.2 prohibits the use of this type of procedure, whether done with hydration or by hand. (https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/)
"Apps should be self-contained in their bundles, and may not read or write data outside the designated container area, nor may they download, install, or execute code which introduces or changes features or functionality of the app, including other apps."